# React Native `Button` or `Pressable` not emitting a `click` event

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

Is there any way to make `Button` or `Pressable` in `react-native` emit a `click` event that can be listened to using web's event listener?

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-field-nb83k?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

**Check now, its incrementing in click events detected.**
here is what i do,

```
 <Button 
     onPress={incrementCounter} 
     title="Doesnt emit click event"
 />
```

Comment: No, the question was asking for a way to emit a native web event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Web events can be listened on RN apps
All you need is to when you press a button on website pass an event like below:

```
window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event);
```

And on RN app side listen to these event by method `onMessage` which is provided by react-native-webview like below:

```
<WebView 
src={{uri: 'https//github.com'}}
onMessage={(event) => {
 if(event.nativeEvent.data=='some-event-name)
    // do somrthing
}}/>
```

for more details checkout [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onmessage)